# Converting this program from 1 function to a modular, multi-function program?

Tags: c++, function, modular-design

I am very new to C++ and have a program which I included below.

The program I am working on reads text from an input file and counts the number of words and number of occurrences of each letter in the text and then prints the results. My program is working fine but the problem is all code is written in the main function and I need to break it up into a couple more functions to make the program modular, but I am unsure of how to go about doing this.

I am sure this is pretty simple but I'm not sure where to start. I was thinking of implementing two void functions, one for reading / interpreting what is read from the data file and another that displays the results; and then call them both in the main function, but I'm not sure what to take as arguments for those functions.

```
int main()
{
    // Declaring variables
    char c; // char that will store letters of alphabet found in the data file
    int count[26] = {0}; // array that will store the # of occurences of each letter
    int words = 1; // int that will store the # of words
    string s; // declaring string found in data file

    // Opening input file stream
    ifstream in;
    in.open("word_data.txt");

    // Reading text from the data file
    getline(in, s);
    //cout << s << endl;

    // If input file fails to open, displays an error message
    if (in.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file did not open correctly" << endl;
    }


    // For loop for interpreting what is read from the data file
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        // Increment word count if new line or space is found
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\n')
            words++;

        //If upper case letter is found, convert to lower case.
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
            s[i] = (tolower(s[i]));

        //If the letters are found, increment the counter for each letter.
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
            count[s[i] - 97]++;
    }


    // Display the words count
    cout << words << " words" << endl;

    // Display the count of each letter
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (count[i] != 0) {
            c = i + 97;
            cout << count[i] << " " << c << endl;
        }
    }
         
    // Always close opened files
    in.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Think of it this way: functions (in theory) should all work at the same "level", and focus on doing a specific thing. So you have code that reads in a file, you have code that iterates over the lines in the file, you have code that processes a line, and you have code that displays the results. Any given function would take the parameters it needs, and return something usable later.

Comment: I'd say you can first try *not* declare all variable at beginning. (which you already do in for loop btw)

Comment: Don't declare all your variables up front. Declare them where you need them and keep their scope as small as possible. Replace 97 with `'a'` in the two places you have it. You used the characters everywhere else, not sure why those two places are different. Consider making a function to update the count for a particular character and another to print the counts out. This isn't a very big program, it doesn't necessarily make sense to do more than that in my opinion.

Comment: you can write functions that you could use later in other projects. for example ```std::string readFile(std::string in) {}``` you can use getline and return the string ```s```

Comment: Here's an idea:  write a function that takes a string and returns the number of words in the string.  You could write another function that takes a `std::map<char, int>&` and a string and reads the characters in the string, updating the `map`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about improving working code

Comment: Re: `My program is working fine` - Are you sure? It appears that you only process the first line of your file

Comment: @VladFeinstein The input file is only 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it like:

```cpp
class FileReader {
public:
    FileReader() {
        // Any init logic goes here...
    }
    ~FileReader() {
        // Always close opened files.
        in.close();
    }

    void open(std::string &filePath) {
        in.open(filePath);
    }

    std::string readLine() {
        std::string s;
        getline(in, s);
        return s;
    }

    bool hasErrors() const { // remove const if you get compile-error here.
        return in.fail();
    }

private:
    ifstream in;
};

class LetterCounter {
public:
    void process(std::string &s) {
        // For loop for interpreting what is read from the data file
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            // Increment word count if new line or space is found
            if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\n')
                words++;

            //If upper case letter is found, convert to lower case.
            if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
                s[i] = (tolower(s[i]));

            //If the letters are found, increment the counter for each letter.
            if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
                count[s[i] - 97]++;
        }
    }

    void logResult() {
        char c; // char that will store letters of alphabet found in the data file.

        // Display the words count
        cout << words << " words" << endl;

        // Display the count of each letter
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (count[i] != 0) {
                c = i + 97;
                cout << count[i] << " " << c << endl;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    int count[26] = {0}; // array that will store the # of occurences of each letter
    int words = 1; // int that will store the # of words
};

int main()
{
    // Opening input file stream.
    FileReader reader;
    reader.open("word_data.txt");

    // Reading text from the data file.
    std::string s = reader.readLine();

    // If input file fails to open, displays an error message
    if (reader.hasErrors()) {
        cout << "Input file did not open correctly" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    LetterCounter counter;
    counter.process(s);
    // Display word and letter count.
    counter.logResult();
    
    return 0;
}
```

> **Note** that I did write without testing (excuse any mistake),
> but this should give you a general idea how it should be.